# Bad : modifier in $ (.)

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to set environment variable in linux and did the same by giving command

```
 export PATH=$PATH:.
```

But getting error Bad : modifier in $ (.).

Can some one help this.
I tried with bash shell and ksh

Answer (score 51):

```
Bad : modifier in $ (.).
```

This is not a [Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) error, nor is it from [Ksh](http://www.kornshell.com/): it's from C-shell or one of its clones such as [Tcsh](http://www.tcsh.org/Home).

You want:

```
setenv PATH ${PATH}:.
```

But you should not put `.` in your `${PATH}`, it's a well-known security risk.

Answer (score 7):

Dont forget to escape the colon

```
setenv PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH\:/disk1/mypath
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try this:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:."
```

I don't like having the current directory in the path, but at the end it's fairly safe.

Comment: "fairly safe"? What does that mean?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: well, i had a co-worker who used to do this: `export PATH=".:${PATH}"` and called a programm he wrote `test` ....

Comment: Sounds "fairly unsafe" to me ;)